# weasyprint single page html

Tags: python, css, weasyprint

I’m trying to convert a html page containing a single table (whose `td`s contain either images or text) to a pdf. I am using `weasyprint` as a python module.

My problem is that weasyprint inserts page breaks in the middle of columns, which I do not want.

What I would like to do is either:

- Rescale (downscale) the page to fit into the height of a page
- Change the page height to fit the height of the content

The size of the table (amount of rows / columns) is variable (I don’t know it in advance).

### Things I tried:

#### 1.

I tried using the css [page.size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) property to change the page size, but it doesn’t work because I don’t know the size of the table in advance.

#### 2.

I tried adding the following

```css
body html{
   height: 100%;
}
```

and adding a lot of `display:block`, but those simply make scrollbars appear, it doesn’t resize the content to fit.

#### 3.

I tried restricting page breaks using

```css
table {
   break-inside: avoid;
}
```

but it didn’t change anything

Comment: `body html` would have definetly not worked since there will never be a `html` inside a `body` unless you nest a document

Comment: Thank you @KJ , you are right, it is an unsolved (issue / feature request) in weasyprint. A workaround is proposed in this issue https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/193

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be a particular solution for the problem you've encountered.
A suitable workarround is to manually insert page breaks before the tables that are being split.

That can be done using the following style:

```css
  break-before: page;
```

you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before)

## Example

You can experiment with this example be removing the `.break-before` class

```css
.break-before {
  break-before: page;
}

.m-top {
  margin-top: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table class="m-top break-before">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, I think the `break-inside: avoid` on table already does what you suggest (prefer breaking before  / after rather than inside the table). It does not solve the problem though, because the table height is bigger than one page

Comment: @Nephanth have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it did not change anything

Comment: But then again, as stated in the question, the `html` page only contains one element: a single table. So adding a pagebreak before/after the table does nothing (since it is the first and the last element).